# Operation: Seedship

Tags: space-colonization, population, future

The year is some time in the future on another planet. The planet is getting overpopulated. The world leaders have convinced the people that there is no overpopulation. But they are very much suffering and on the brink of collapse. The government has a giant plan to kill half the planet.

There is this group of people that have plans to colonize a nearby planet in a couple of years. The operation is call Seedship. As a seed has potential for something great. The operation is unknown to everybody except the small organization. They will have success. They have no limit on spacecraft. No one believes them and they have very limited time before the government executes their plan.

**How could they possibly convince the planet that they should come with them.**

> "Mankind was born on Earth. But it was never meant to die here."
>
> -Interstellar

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason it published before I was finished.

Comment: How much time do they have to get everyone off planet? If they can afford a spacecraft, why haven't all the rich and smart people left long ago?

Comment: The whole planet?  At no time in Earth's history has there ever been even one example where the *whole planet* was convinced of anything.  There are people even today who actually believe in [inedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inedia) or the ability to live only on air and light - we can't even agree that we all need to eat solid food.  Are you sure you need to convince the entire planet? or would a reasonable number of adherents be enough?  (Can you believably claim to have enough ships to move the whole planetary population?)

Comment: I would assume the intent behind the phrase was how could they convince the majority of the planet its a good idea and that they should send a large chunk of people. though I remember reading somewhere that colonization is never an effective way to reduce population, the short explanation is you cant send enough people to a new colony to significantly reduce the population without overwhelming the new colony and a new colony's potential to take new people grows slower than the population growth at home.

Comment: This seems off-topic as you are asking us to construct a plot for you, which we don't do on WB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The organization teams up with the government.  Each can advance the interest of the other.**

If you are going to get rid of half the people, you need to be efficient about it unless you want some Rwandan genocide chaos.  The governments need some method to get rid of these people.  They need it to be quick and quiet and clean or there will be a revolution.    The organization can help.  They have a great method of getting rid of people.

Have a demonstration project in a city.  The government rounds up the people and delivers them to the organization. The organization loads them up and launches them into space.  No people are left; neat and clean.  The governments like that!

The government was ready to make half the population disappear, for the good of the many.  The government is not monsters or some incoming asteroid armageddon.  They do not hate these people or want them to suffer; they just need them gone.  If they can be disappeared peacefully and not get hurt, that is equally good and in many ways better.  Peacefully disappeared is what the organization will do with them.

Answer (score 1):

After writing some explanation.. isn't the Government = Thanos?

There will always be people who will support a plan, and people who will go against it. It is highly HIGHLY unlikely that a majority of the population will believe in a small group with no recognition that they can bring anyone to another planet and colonize it. (See Mars One project)

People can only unite with each other if it's to affect their personal life, alongside their loved ones. "Overpopulation" is not an ideal reason to colonize another planet, as there are people that are not affected by such. Why would someone living in a comfortable life with their family decide to move to an unfamiliar world where there is no guarantee of safety?

I think that convincing the entire population of the planet to do a single objective is impossible. Though, you can convince a majority of the population by again, through a reason that will affect their personal lives. The killing half the population is a perfect example. Have the plans exposed! I doubt that someone will believe in a government that will perform genocide to its own people. By providing a solid fact that will threaten their personal lives, people will start to act.

Answer (score 0):

publish the full plans of the operation on the internet with a nice web campaign coordinated with tv adverts and radio, it helps that they could use the catchy phrase "come with us and you wont be killed by the government"

However that doesn't seem like a good story (maybe it is), so the next question is why wouldn't that plan work. Without constraints the solution is easy. I imagine there would be great resistance from the people who would be left behind about the resources being used in a way that wont benefit them. In the end the answer would be to make a great pr campaign. unless the government uses force or suppression to stop them then its more about how do you get the information to the people, underground movements, uprising, civil unrest and distributing propaganda.

So it depends on how everyone reacts to the first plan.